# Font size best practices?

Tags: flutter, font-size

I was wondering what are some of the best practices for font size in flutter?

How big should page titles/subtitles/body-text/subtext etc...

There are guidelines for android and ios but I haven't found one for flutter.

Comment: see [TextTheme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)

Comment: "guidelines for android and ios but I haven't found one for flutter." -- well flutter is a framework that allows you to develop for both platforms at once, it's not an actual platform. So you can follow the Android guidelines or iOS guidelines or both. If you want material design for your app, you should follow material design guidelines.

Comment: @danypata yep i know but my concern is with the different pixel calculation. Not sure if I'm getting my point along correctly what i mean by my question is that is there a clear guideline that tells you for example a title should be xPixels (which translates to what platform specific guidelines suggest it should be)